# Как трансформировать блок без трансформации текста внутри блока на css

Tags: html, css

Как трансформировать block, не трансформируя текст. То есть на текст не должная повлиять трансформация.

```css
.transform_items {
  width: 40%;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  perspective: 600px;
}
.block {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 5px solid green;
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
}
.block a {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="transform_items">
  <li class="block"><a>Пункт1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="block"><a>Пункт2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="block"><a>Пункт3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: поверните `a` в обратную сторону на -30

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не поможет

Comment: @VenZell, действительно не поможет

Comment: @VenZell значит переходим на псвевдоэлементы) О. смотрю и ответ появился...значит я зря начал писать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, одинаковые мысли посетили) Я чуть раньше ответил, чем вы написали комментарий.

Comment: @VenZell Кстати, тоже сначала хотел развернуть текст в обратную сторону. Но почему-то не сработало...

Comment: Текст модифицирован, как и блок, обратно развернуть не выйдет уже.

Comment: @VenZell да я так и догадывался, но проверить всё же захотелось)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вращать псевдоэлемент `::before`, расположенный под текстом, а не сам блок.

```css
.transform_items {
  width: 40%;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  perspective: 600px;
}
.block,
.block::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
}
.block::before {
  content: '';
  border: 5px solid green;
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
}
.block a {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="transform_items">
  <li class="block"><a>Пункт1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="block"><a>Пункт2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="block"><a>Пункт3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```